# I Can't Get Bigcommerce Global Variables to Work Anymore

Tags: javascript, global-variables, bigcommerce

For some reason I can not get the BC global variables to work at all as of yesterday.  They won't return anything, and instead just spit errors, mainly the one after line 5 below.   for example:

```
console.log(%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%%);  //returns only errors
console.log(%%GLOBAL_StoreName%%);  //returns only errors
console.log("hello"); //returns "hello" (as it should)

OUTPUT - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

I have tried putting the code directly in the body of several different pages (in script tags), and I've also tried just putting the code in normal .js docs.

I have tried simple console.logs, and simple conditionals, but I can't get the variables to A. stop causing errors and B. return anything

```
1|  if ( %%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%% === 3 ) { 
2|     console.log("you are three");  
3|     } else {
4|     console.log("you are not 3");  
5|    }

OUTPUT - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %  (for line 1)
```

I have also received the error a few times that says it doesn't recognize "===", or "=".  (always talking about the strict equal in an if statement)

Any ideas?  Did something change in the last few days?  I have never run into problems with the BC global variables, and now I can't get a single one to return anything.  Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Based off of Alyss's comment, I then tried this:

```
var anotherBcGlobalTestingOfVariab = %%GLOBAL_StoreName%%;

  console.log("----store name below------");
  console.log(anotherBcGlobalTestingOfVariab);
  console.log("----store name above------");

RESULT: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Removed the semicolon, changed the BC variable:

```
var anotherBcGlobalTestingOfVariab = %%GLOBAL_CustomerName%%

  console.log("----customer name below------");
  console.log(anotherBcGlobalTestingOfVariab);
  console.log("----customer name above------");

RESULT:
----customer name below------
undefined
----customer name above------
```

Interesting what happens when I set a variable equal to %%GLOBAL_StoreName%% *without* the semicolon, same example as directly above, but different BC variable:

```
  var bcGlobalTestingOfVariab = %%GLOBAL_StoreName%%;

    console.log("----store name below------");
    console.log(bcGlobalTestingOfVariab);
    console.log("----store name above------");

  Uncaught ReferenceError: CENSORED is not defined
```

CENSORED is the name of the store, so somehow it returned the store name, but in the context of an error.  I have tried several other BC variables with the same result.

SECOND EDIT:

```
if (%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%% === 9) {
  console.log("congrats, it only took you 20 hours");
} else {
  console.log("you are not a nine");
}
```

placed in default.html at the bottom in script tags...first time I have been able to make something work. YES IT WORKED.  I can't imagine what the problem would be especially when you use store wide variables.

Comment: have you tried making a var equal to the global?

Comment: I just tried and didn't have any better luck.  First it told me that the semicolon at the end of the variable assignment was a syntax error.  I removed it.  Then it told me that "<" was a syntax error (from a commented out piece of code so I erased it).  I set %%GLOBAL_StoreName%% equal to a variable.  I console.log'd the variable.  The result was undefined.

Comment: can you email me your store URL at alyss@bigcommerce.com?

Comment: Try creating the variables in the <head> if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to wrap the Globals in quotes**:

```
var a = "%%GLOBAL_Example%%";
console.log("%%GLOBAL_Example%%");
```

---

These Globals are evaluated by the template engine *(php)*, and are sent to the browser *(the client)* as already being evaluated. For example, if `%%GLOBAL_Example%%` evaluates to `Some Example String`, then take a look at how it appears to the JavaScript interpreter when not enclosed within quotes:

```
var a = Some Example String;
console.log(Some Example String);
```

The syntax error here should now be obvious, and you can *View Page Source* to see firsthand how these Globals appear. Since there are no quotes, the JS interpreter thinks you are referring to a variable, so then after it parses the first word, it fails with an `Unexpected Token` error, because it's only expecting a select group of characters (such as '+' or new line) *rather than* the characters of your continued string.

---

The exception here would be if the Global evaluates to a number. In this case, quotes are not needed, and is not recommended *(type conflict)*. This is important to note since you are using the `===` comparison operator in one of your conditional statements, which checks for equivalence in both `type` *(int, string, etc)* **AND** `value`. So your condition will fail if you attempt to use `===` between a string and a number.

**Example**:

```
/* "9" is a string, whereas 9 (without quotes) is a number  */
console.log("9" === 9 ? 'Equal' : 'Not Equal!'); //Prints 'Not Equal!'
console.log(9   === 9 ? 'Equal' : 'Not Equal!'); //Prints 'Equal'
```

As a final note, semicolons are completely optional in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried doing what you said in the simplest way for 2 different variables, one thats supposed to return a number, and one a string  -  the non-quoted ones produced an error (Unexpected Token %) and the second returned the actual characters inside the quotes, so it returned, "%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupId%%", same for the one thats supposed to return a string.  Note that it's working for me inside <script> tags above the end of a body, but it's NOT working in my .js files, and did b4 (I know these files are linked correctly in the header, I've been a console.log maniac about it)

Comment: @Tron Okay, so in this case the Globals aren't being evaluated by the template engine because they are out of reach. BigCommerce is very picky about where Globals will work. I don't think they would work in a JS file, but could you just move the JS inline to the most closely associated template file?

Comment: thanks love, exactly what I have started doing because all of a sudden the BC globals in my .js files stopped working - they did work before - except now I am running into places where they aren't even working in script tags.  For example, I need to be able to reference a CustomerGroupId in the ExpressCheckoutTemplates but am having no success.  Also, having it sitting in the body of my templates is definitely not ideal.

Comment: @Tron I'd recommend placing your main JS app in the footer instead, and then just assign the BC Globals as a global JS variable in the relevant template file. For example, if `%%CustomerGroupId%%` only works on `a.html`, then in that template file, make the variable assignment - `var a = %%CustomerGroupId%%`, and so then you can reference that variable `a` from the JS located in your footer.html.

Comment: Haha, ehh. It's definitely bad architecture, take notes on where you have things saved - It will save time in the future. I'd say keep playing around to see where you can and cannot use the BC Globals. Me personally, I might include my main JS app in the header, and then call it / do some logic from the various template files so that I can access and share the BC Globals while keeping the use case specific to whatever template file requires it.

Comment: it works in certain places, but not really in the spots where I need it to, like in any of the checkout pages.  I can get a first name or last name, but I can not get a group number, which is crucial because of certain personalizations.  Any ideas?